# Typescript configuration with src and test

Tags: typescript, npm, emacs, tsconfig

I have multiple TypeScript projects where I separated the source code from the tests to their directories (`src` and `test`). In the final package I would like to include only the source code without the tests since the runtime does not need to know anything about the test files, fixtures, etc.

If I have the following settings in the `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // compiler options
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

And these in the `package.json`:

```
{
  // usual settings
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "files": [
    "dist/**/*.js",
    "dist/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Then the final package only includes the source code in the desired directory structure, which is what I want to see, but my environment is having issues. I am using [Doom Emacs](https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs) and for the tests tide throws errors like this:

```
Error from syntax checker typescript-tide: Error processing request. No Project.
Error: No Project.
    at Object.ThrowNoProject (/Users/ikaraszi/.../node_modules/typescript/lib/tsserver.js:152133:23)
```

If I change the `tsconfig.json` settings to include the `test` directory, then the tide errors go away:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // compiler options
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDirs": ["src", "test"]
  }
}
```

But then the directory structure for the distribution changes and there will be a `dist/src` and `dist/test` that I would like to avoid since then the users of my libraries would need to use strange import statements:

```
import { foo } from 'library/dist/src/foo';
```

I would like to avoid the extra `src` if possible, the `dist` is ugly enough but that is given.

I tried with multiple settings change the `include` property to have `src` and `test`, but the builds ends up in the `dist` directory with the same nested structure:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // compiler options
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "include": ["src", "test"]
}
```

I also tried to play with the `package.json` settings without any luck. Is there anything I can do without adding an extra step to the build process to remove the unnecessary extra directories?

Comment: Often you want different _types_ in the tests, too, so you have a second `tsconfig.test.json` that extends `tsconfig.json` and brings in the extra types and files. I'm not familiar with tide (or emacs!), though, and a quick scan of the docs doesn't seem to indicate you can configure it to look at anything other than `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: This solution could work if I would switch it. I would have a `tsconfig.build.json` with the build settings and a `tsconfig.json` where I include both the source code and the tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [@jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe)'s comment I ended up with two tsconfig files:

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/node14/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["src", "test"]
}
```

And a `tsconfig.build.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2018",
    "noUnusedLocals": true
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

And in the `package.json`:

```
{
  // usual settings
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "files": [
    "dist/**/*.js",
    "dist/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc --build tsconfig.build.json",
    // other scripts
  }
}
```